# Using Juggernaut can you subscribe to and publish wildcard Redis events?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, socket.io, juggernaut

In the same way Redis provides a PSUBSCRIBE interface for wildcard events, can you subscribe to wildcards from the client (browser) using Juggernaut? I'm looking for something like this:

From the client:

```
var jug = new Juggernaut();
jug.subscribe('event:'+event.id+':*', function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

And then from the server:

```
Juggernaut.publish("event:#{event.id}:foshiz", data)
```

Comment: I'll be looking into this more over the next week or so. Anyone have any additional insights?